# How do SO URLs self correct themselves if they are mistyped?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If an extra character (like a period, comma or a bracket or even alphabets) gets accidentally added to URL on the stackoverflow.com domain, a 404 error page is not thrown. Instead, URLs self correct themselves & the user is led to the relevant webpage.

For instance, the extra 4 letters I added to the end of a valid SO URL to demonstrate this would be automatically removed when you access the below URL -
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-booksasdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)

I guess this has something to do with ASP.NET MVC Routing. How is this feature implemented?

Comment: That link will self correct because it's only for SEO I believe, as the actual imporant value in the url is the id.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812 works as well. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812abc however, does not.

Comment: Can anyone help me with some sample code to show how the SEO-friendly portion of the URL is scrubbed? Apparently, there is URL correction & redirection to the scrubbed URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because EVERYTHING after `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812` is ignored. It is just there to make the link, if posted somewhere, if more speaking.

Internally the URL is mapped to a handler, e.g., by a rewrite, that transforms into something like: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions.php?id=194812` (just an example, don't know the correct internal URL)

This also makes the URL search engine friendly, besides being more readable to humans.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is quite simple to explain I guess, even without knowing the code behind it:
The text is just candy for search engines and people reading the URL:

[This URL will work as well, with the complete text removed!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/)

The only part really important is the question ID that's also embedded in the "path".